# Error in sql command c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying insert some data into a database table using sql commands. I keep getting this error:

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@MC"
```

**Code:**

```
void CreateModule() {
    Query = "INSERT INTO TblModules (Module_Code, Module_Name, Date,Start_Time, Duration) values ( @MC, @MN, @DATE, @ST, @DURATION)";

    theReader = dc.ExecuteStatement(Query);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MC", ModuleCodeTxt.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MN", ModulenameTxt.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", MyDateTimePicker.Value);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ST", comboBoxTime.SelectedItem);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DURATION", comboBoxDuration.SelectedItem);

    MessageBox.Show(" Module Created");
    conn.CloseConnection();
}
```

Comment: sorry thats meant to bo conn... as in connection

Comment: can you show us ExecuteStatement method?

Answer (score 7):

You should give value to your parameters **before** you execute the query

```
command.CommandText = Query;  // <-- don't forget to set command text 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MC", ModuleCodeTxt.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MN", ModulenameTxt.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", MyDateTimePicker.Value);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ST", comboBoxTime.SelectedItem);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DURATION", comboBoxDuration.SelectedItem);

//execute the query here, maybe you want this?
theReader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

By the way where is your `command` ? your `Query` variable is just a string literal that holds command text.I don't know what is your method doing but I think you should pass your `command` to your `ExecuteStatement` and change your method ofcourse.